# Hash value outside of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, hash

I need to use the " \ Hash :: check " out of Laravel .

I do not want to install Laravel because the project is very small, but all passwords are hashed with Laravel .

how I can use the Hash :: check out Laravel ?

Thanks!

Comment: full list of functions [here](http://php.net/manual/it/ref.password.php)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PHP >= 5.5 then you can do hash verification by using `password_verify()` function. Internally laravel uses the same function while doing `Hash::check()`.

For example:

```
$hashedPassword = '$2y$10$XEq0uTegk/KlkuOR.xMKfenIH9XpstjTau2qBrQoGiuyGgd/NHXjO';
$password = 'password';

if(password_verify($password, $hashedPassword))
     echo 'Password is valid!';
else
     echo 'Invalid password.';
```